# PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'

Tags: angular, phantomjs

I use PhantomJS 2.1.1 with Angular 4 on MacOS and Linux, and I encounter the following error when I run `ng test`, does anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:1318
```

My tsConfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

> Note : 
>   I have read a number of posts including Previously answered by stack overflow but haven't found anything that has worked. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Currently experiencing the same and no luck w/ the polyfills.

Comment: it's old but this was resolved, it was something related to es version

Comment: @AbdulManan Would you mind to share your solution?

Comment: It was a syntax error I forgot comma after the variable declaration.eg ```const port = 3000
   width=43;``` here I need a comma after 3000

Answer (score 0):

add/enable the below snippet in polyfills.ts file, this will resolve this issue.

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';`
```